# Get all pairs of strings (DNA) seperated by a distance of Hamming = 1

Tags: string, algorithm, hamming-distance

I have an array of DNA sequences, like:

> AA 
>  TA  
>  AC 
>  CC

and I search a faster way to calculate the hamming distance between all sequences pairs (maybe by sorting...), then naive approach (O(N^2))

```
For motif1 in array
   For motif2 in array
      calculate Hamming_Distance(motif1 , motif2)
   end
end
```

I need the sequence of pairs that have an Hamming distance = 1

Comment: What do you want those distances for?

Comment: You want to calculate N(N-1)/2 distances. How can it be better than O(N^2)? Just reporting your results is O(N^2).

Comment: construct an graphe, where edges represents an hamming distance of 1. For exemple, for this array:   TA -- AA -- AC -- CA ....

Comment: Actually, I'm interested only by Hamming distances that are equal to 1

Comment: OK... Please update your question

Comment: Is it DNA by any chance? With just 4 characters allowed, there might be better tricks.

Comment: Yes, exact. It's DNA sequences

Comment: Assuming there is limited space of allowed characters (DNA in your case), you could try to sum up all characters (with 0,1,2,3 values assigned to each), sort all strings by resulting 'hash' and only compare ones which are less than 4 away from each other. You will still get a lot of false comparisons, but at least you will filter out considerable amount of obvious negatives. It might improve things for reasonably distributed strings. And you can do sorting in linear time for integers (radix/bucket sort). Said that, I'm quite sure that there is a lot of prior art for DNA efficient comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the trick. But it's less than 3 away from each other, no ? (A(0) replaced by T(3))

Comment: It is <=3 (max 3 away) or <4 (less than 4). Create some unit tests to make sure it works as expected ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your n >> k, then you can try following

Your original complexity is O(n*n*k), where k is length of the sequence (as Hamming distance comparison requires k steps). Let's try to improve on that.

1. Create hashmap with all strings in it (complexity O(n*k) because of hashing)
2. For each string in your input, create all strings which are 1 away from it and see if they are contained in hashmap - if yes, you have found a pair (complexity O(n*k*k) because you need to hash O(k) each of k variations for each of n strings)

With that, you have replaced O(n*n*k) with O(n*k*k), which should be beneficial if n >> k.

For k >> n you probably don't really care about n^2 part, so use trivial algorithm.

For k near n, you can try what I have suggested in comment

1. Create pseudo-hash for each sequence, by summing all letters with 0,1,2,3 (complexity O(n*k))
2. Sort them (complexity O(n*logn) if you use out of the box sorting, or O(n) with radix/bucket sort)
3. Compare pairs going through sorted sequence, looking only at things which are max 3 away from each other (complexity depending on your case, will be O(n*n*k) in most pathological case, but with real world data it can be closer to O(n*k*f(n)) where f(n) would be very very small)